# Entity reference - hide some references in multiple-reference field edit widget

Tags: forms, entities

I have a node (group) with an entity reference field that is used to link it to other nodes (stations). The relationship between them is 1:N (one group : many stations).

The problem is that I need to limit the edit widget so that certain users can see (and also edit) only specific station links. I have no problems with limiting which stations can be added, I know that I can easily do that via custom validation + entityreference selection widget.

The real trouble is with limiting which already existing references to stations can be deleted / viewed. Imagine that I have this structure:

```
user1
user2

Group1
-station1
-station2
//User1 is allowed to see (and edit) only station1, user2 only station2.
```

Then I'd need to edit the Group1 edit form in a way that when user1 access it he/she only sees the station1 in the stations references widget (and can therefore remove only that referece). Following the same principle, when user2 access the group1 edit form, he/she can only see (and edit) the station2 reference.

I know how to limit the deletion itself via setting the '#disable' property of the individual reference...

```
$form['entity_reference_field_name']['und'][1]['target_id']['#disabled'] = true;
```

...but that doesn't hide, just disables it for removal.

There's also the possibility of setting the '#access' property of it which actually hides the record, the problem is that it looks just terribly ugly (and like a clear 'hack').

```
$form['entity_reference_field_name']['und'][1]['target_id']['#access'] = false;
```

[image: Looks ugly]

I can't unset the reference because it would delete it.

So, does anyone have any idea how to it? Preferably without having to clone the entity reference module and editing its core.

Comment: Do you have anything in place so that users in Group 1 have "some" role which the users from Group 2 do not have. And similarly a 2nd role for Group 2, which Group 1 users  do not have? If you don't have such a roles related separation, can you think of one to have a role for each group? In that case there is, I think, a straight forward solution ...

Comment: Unfortunately no, the access is determined dynamically based on a few things including but not being limited to permission.