# Add-only widget for entity reference field

Tags: entities

Is there any widget for Entity Reference field, which would allow users **to only add new values**, without possibility to see existing values? I know, I could probably achieve it by using CSS, but I wonder, if there is any cleaner solution to this problem.

I know, I probably could use info in [Entity reference - hide some references in multiple-reference field edit widget](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109017/entity-reference-hide-some-references-in-multiple-reference-field-edit-widget), but that would also need to be adjusted.

Comment: If there is, it's probably a custom module or something. CSS is the way to go IMO